# What does it mean when we see class C = myarray in a template declaration?

Tags: c++

While browsing the standard I found some syntax in the template declaration that confused me:

```
template <typename T> class myarray;

template </*...*/, template <typename T> class C = myarray>
```

What does `class C = myarray` mean? Is it a default parameter? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a *default* value for the template template argument. If you don't specify the argument, it will default to `myarray`.

Example:

```
template <typename> class Foo;
template <typename> class Bar;

template <typename T, template <typename> class C = Foo>
class Zip
{
    typedef C<T> type;  // example use of "C"
    // ...
};

Zip<int, Bar> x;  // OK
Zip<int>      y;  // OK, y has type Zip<int, Foo>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is basically the "default value" for the argument.